# Create date from text in iOS Shortcuts

Tags: ios, shortcut

I want to take a string and turn it into a date but I cannot find the format how to enter the text so it is recognized as date. Please see the screenshot.

1. asking for the date as text (this is just to try it, as actually I get the date from a text property)
2. Convert it to date
3. Output as formatted date -> date conversion error
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer can be found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250512799?answerId=250982265022#250982265022).
They key is to not use the magic variable directly in "Use date", but select "Given date" and then use the magic variable for that. This way a format can be specified.

Answer (score -2):

Use NSDate formatter to go from string to date

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[itemOnServerDict objectForKey:@"lastTimeSeen"]];

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let enUSLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.locale = enUSLocale
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to set the date format as the text is  so

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//here you have to pass the format of the date in the text
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
```

then with this date you could parse to new string with new format like this

```
 //set the desired format to the date
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
let dateString = dateFormatter.strin(from: date)
```